# Assign dict values to list if they exist, otherwise none

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Right now, i have something like that:

```
media_info = MediaInfo.parse(file_path).to_data()
local_file_info = [ media_info['tracks'][1]['frame_rate'],
                    media_info['tracks'][1]['other_display_aspect_ratio'],
                    media_info['tracks'][2]['other_sampling_rate'],
                    media_info['tracks'][2]['other_channel_s'],
                    media_info['tracks'][3]['Format']]
```

How can i dumbproof this to assign None instead of throwing IndexError when element doesn't exist? (Example: file parsed with MediaInfo doesn't have subtitle track in video file, so there is no 3rd track)

I know i could do it the dirty way:

```
try:
    local_file_info.append(media_info['tracks'][1]['frame_rate'])
except IndexError
    local_file_info.append(None)

try:
    local_file_info.append(media_info['tracks'][1]['other_display_aspect_ratio'])
except IndexError
    local_file_info.append(None)

try:
    local_file_info.append(media_info['tracks'][2]['other_sampling_rate'])
except IndexError
    local_file_info.append(None)

try:
    local_file_info.append(media_info['tracks'][2]['other_channel_s'])
except IndexError
    local_file_info.append(None)

try:
    local_file_info.append(media_info['tracks'][3]['Format'])
except IndexError
    local_file_info.append(None)
```

But that just looks horrible and i'm sure there is better way to do that.

Comment: Why not just do it with for-loop?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious problem with your code is the massive code duplication. Two useful tools for reducing code duplication are

- **Loops:** Rather than manually accessing `media_info` 5 times, write a loop that does it for you.
- **Functions:** Rather than copy/pasting the `try...except` block 5 times, wrap it in a function.

Ideally, you should do both:

```
media_keys = [
    (1, 'frame_rate'),
    (1, 'other_display_aspect_ratio'),
    (2, 'other_samping_rate'),
    (2, 'other_channel_s'),
    (3, 'Format')
]

def get_media_info(index, key):
    try:
        return media_info['tracks'][index][key]
    except IndexError:
        return None

local_file_info = [get_media_info(*keys) for keys in media_keys]
```

Comment: I like your implementation better :). List comprehensions are the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

a quick fix would be using if conditions

```
if 3 in media_info['tracks'].keys():
    local_file_info.append(media_info['tracks'][3]['Format'])
else:
    local_file_info.append(None)
```

but it still doesn't fix your problem, since it still looks horrible but atleast its not the dirty way

Comment: "Not the dirty way"? This is far dirtier than the OP's solution. You can't make code better by making it less DRY.